# Print column name and their values from SQL Alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How could I print column name and their values using SQLAlchemy in python?

For ex: I have a *USER* table, which contains 2 fields *ID* & *NAME*.

```
ID  NAME
1   John
2   Stella
```

I need something similar to this mysql query: `select id as User_ID from USER where id = '1';`

Currently, I am using the following query to get just the values:

```
meta = MetaData(engine)
users = Table('USER', meta, autoload=True)
selectQuery = select([users.c.ID, users.c.NAME]).where(users.c.ID == '1')
```

Executing above query I am getting:

```
('1', 'John')
```

Instead I need this:

```
ID  NAME
1   John
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? You have the column names already, why can't you form your data from that? Just in case, a `Column` object has an attribute `name`, which is the name as text. Your "I need this" looks like the representation of a Pandas DataFrame.

Comment: You should read ["What is the XY problem?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so that in the future you may ask about the problem you're really trying to solve.